# android&/sqlite: cursor causes problems

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have this error with an sqlite-related cursor. i subclass SQLiteOpenHelper to get access to the database. Then, I access the DB and close my cursor directly afterwards. nevertheless, this results in an error when  I close the activity:

The code looks like this:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM table_bla LIMIT 1";
Cursor cursor = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase().rawQuery(sql, null);

cursor.moveToFirst();
String x = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("x"));
cursor.close();
```

And I get this:

```
03-14 15:34:55.945: E/Database(3825): close() was never explicitly called on database '/data/data/my.project/databases/myDB.db' 
03-14 15:34:55.945: E/Database(3825): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
03-14 15:34:55.945: E/Database(3825):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1847)
03-14 15:34:55.945: E/Database(3825):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:820)
03-14 15:34:55.945: E/Database(3825):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:854)
03-14 15:34:55.945: E/Database(3825):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:847)
03-14 15:34:55.945: E/Database(3825):   at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:572)
03-14 15:34:55.945: E/Database(3825):   at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:203)
03-14 15:34:55.945: E/Database(3825):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:118)
03-14 15:34:55.945: E/Database(3825):   at my.project.StartScreen.onResume(StartScreen.java:35)
03-14 15:34:55.945: E/Database(3825):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1150)
03-14 15:34:55.945: E/Database(3825):   at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3832)
03-14 15:34:55.945: E/Database(3825):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2231)
03-14 15:34:55.945: E/Database(3825):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2256)
03-14 15:34:55.945: E/Database(3825):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1789)
03-14 15:34:55.945: E/Database(3825):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
03-14 15:34:55.945: E/Database(3825):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:939)
03-14 15:34:55.945: E/Database(3825):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-14 15:34:55.945: E/Database(3825):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-14 15:34:55.945: E/Database(3825):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
03-14 15:34:55.945: E/Database(3825):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-14 15:34:55.945: E/Database(3825):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-14 15:34:55.945: E/Database(3825):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
03-14 15:34:55.945: E/Database(3825):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
03-14 15:34:55.945: E/Database(3825):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

anyone knows what causes this?

Comment: did you close the database object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite your code like that:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM table_bla LIMIT 1";
SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(sql, null);

cursor.moveToFirst();
String x = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("x"));
cursor.close();
database.close();
```

Otherwise you get a connection to the database you never close, which causes the problem.

Comment: Additionally, he should be getting a readable database instead of a writeable database since he's not making any modifications to the DB.

Comment: does not really matter - `getReadableDatabase()` will give you a writable if it can. Edit: well it's safer to request a readable db since that tries harder to get a db.

Answer (score 2):

this is because you need to close the access to de DB before exiting the app, I think that this code doesn't make a force close.